# How does the Admin SDK behave if a Firestore operation fails?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using the Firebase Admin SDK with Cloud Functions. The function does multiple writes to several Firestore collections, which need to be consistent.

Now i am not sure how the Firestore operation behave if a valid operation like a write to a document fails (maybe through cosmic radiation or something which is similar unlikely).

Does the operation instantly return an error or is there some kind of retry or error correction mechanism?

Maybe this is a silly question and has nothing to do with the SDK itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you have multiple documents to write that all must land at the same time, atomically, you should be using a [batch or transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) in order to make that happen.  If any document would fail to write for any reason, then nothing will happen for any of the documents referenced.  If you instead choose to do several write operations, you would have to figure out to reliably roll back each change individually, which is going to be a lot of work.

If you do get an error, I don't believe there are any guarantees about the conditions of that error.  You would likely want to retry on your own, unless you're able to determine that the error is not transient.  To make retries reliable, you could [enable the retry configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries) on the function, allow the error to escape the function (don't catch the error), and let Cloud Functions invoke it again for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as i understand there are no guarantees for successful operations. Retrying the function sounds interesting. What would you recommend working with? Smaller 'stateless' functions or functions which use Firestore as persistent storage? Or should i not use cloud functions for sensitive data?

Comment: Functions should ideally be as stateless as possible. I don't think security is really an issue here, as long as the function is doing what it's supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 1):

It will throw an error. If you notice every method use has a callback with succes or error.

If you are using something like await on node, you should then try/catch

If you have more than one operation and the procedure should be atomical and/or all or nothing, then use batches

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

When a Functions encounters if the error is not handle then the Function crash, you can modify the retries for Functions

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately i cannot mark both answers as correct :(

Comment: It seems my answer was first than the other xD @Sebe